# How to configure video camera by directshow.net?

Tags: c#, .net, directshow.net

I found some samples that use directshow.net(in C#) to capture video from camera, but i didn't see any sample about configuring video (such as Backlight compensation , Brightness, Contrast, Sharpness, White balance, Hue...) , settings for camera (Exposure,Focus,Pan,Roll,Tilt,Zoom...), video output format,...
I'm very appreciated if you give me a link of samples or documents that guide how to do that with directshow.net C#.

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into sample code showing how to obtain and use [`IAMVideoProcAmp` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd376033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Standard samples don't demo it, however it's defined and available.

For the record, the helpful question which you already found: [How can i set brightness for camera using IAMVideoProcAmp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613847/how-can-i-set-brightness-for-camera-using-iamvideoprocamp)