# How can i set brightness for camera using IAMVideoProcAmp?

Tags: c#, webcam, directshow.net

I'm trying to use IAMVideoProcAmp (directshow.net C#) to set brightness for a microsoft camera (lifecam studio).
I refer the solution from [here](http://www.dailycode.info/Blog/post/2009/02/05/DirectShow-how-to-adjust-properties-of-a-Webcam.aspx). This solution uses IAMVideoProcAmp to set brightness for camera. After i connect to device by calling

`DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);`

i set the brightness of camera. But it's seem to be not work when i call Set() function of IAMVideoProcAmp

```
int Set(
          VideoProcAmpProperty Property, // VideoProcAmpProperty
          int lValue,          // Value to set
          VideoProcAmpFlags Flags  // VideoProcAmp_Flags_* 
       );
```

I tried to set various valid values for this function but there no effect on camera.
I can get the max/min/default value of brightness property of camera by function:

```
int GetRange(
            VideoProcAmpProperty Property,         // Which property to query
            out int pMin,          // Range minimum
            out int pMax,          // Range maxumum
            out int pSteppingDelta,// Step size
            out int pDefault,      // Default value
            out VideoProcAmpFlags pCapsFlags     // VideoProcAmpFlags
            );
```

And it gave me max = 255, min = 30, default = 133, pCapsFlags = manual.

I also used Microsoft lifecam software to adjust the brightness and it makes effect on camera immediately. but the max/min value of brightness are max = 2.5, min = -2.5
Please show me the way to set brightness of camera and why the max/min values that i get are different from value on property pages?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: i used IAMVideoProcAmp::Set value to camera,and then call IAMVideoProcAmp::Get i received correct value that i set, but the brightness of camera is not change.

Comment: can you check if these sample code is correct, i refer sample code from here http://www.dailycode.info/Blog/post/2009/02/05/DirectShow-how-to-adjust-properties-of-a-Webcam.aspx

Comment: Some other properties are effective on camera right after i set value, but VideoProcAmpProperty.Brightness is not effective. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last i figured out that `IAMVideoProcAmp::Set` is not work because Microsoft lifecam software. This software is installed along with installing of camera driver. The TrueColor feature of this software is the point of this problem, when i turn TrueColor on from this software, then i cannot use `IAMVideoProcAmp::Set` to adjust the brightness from my app anymore. Just uninstall Microsoft lifecam  then it works as my desire. Hope this info will help someone get same problem to me.